# NoClassDefFoundError com/google/api/services/storage/Storage$Builder

Tags: java, google-app-engine

After performing GCS image upload steps and downloading latest file from URL

```
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download
```

below are the code.

```
    public class GcsExample {

   private static GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
// Error during initialization 

    public void doPost(String gcsFilename, byte[] data) throws IOException {

            GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename("niranttest2.appspot.com", gcsFilename);
            com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions.Builder fileOptionsBuilder = new GcsFileOptions.Builder();
            fileOptionsBuilder.mimeType("image/jpeg");

            GcsFileOptions fileOptions = fileOptionsBuilder.build();
            GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, fileOptions);

            // write file out
            BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));

            List<byte[]> allBytes = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
            allBytes.add(data);

            for (byte[] b : allBytes) {
                outStream.write(b);
            }
            outStream.close();
            outputChannel.close();
        }

    }
```

this code is working fine in localhost but in production gcsService is not initializing.
Logs on Server is below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/storage/Storage$Builder
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.oauth.OauthRawGcsService.<init>(OauthRawGcsService.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.oauth.OauthRawGcsServiceFactory.createOauthRawGcsService(OauthRawGcsServiceFactory.java:41)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:59)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:44)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:75)
    at com.sparks.nirant.serviceImpl.GcsExample.<clinit>(GcsExample.java:30)
```

below are the libraries I'm using

```
/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.28.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints-deps.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.28.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/asm-4.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-android-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-appengine-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-gson-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-jackson2-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-java6-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-protobuf-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-servlet-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-xml-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-android-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-appengine-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-gson-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jackson-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jdo-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-protobuf-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-xml-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-appengine-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-java6-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.21.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/transaction-api-1.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.5.jar/
```

I believe it error is because of appengine-gcs-client-0.5.jar file but I have already tried using appengine-gcs-client-0.3.jar which is again throwing same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're using raw storage client (as I see from `GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService`), I guess because you're using it outside of App Engine. Maybe it's required anyway.

This class is coming from `google-api-services-storage` lib, you should add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev66-1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Igor, after adding above jar file I got below error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone

Which is solved through its library, finally it worked. 1000XThanks :)